# How to assign column names from a source data frame to a target df

Tags: r

I have a df called "target" with column names V1:V200. I want to replace these column names with character strings that are stored in a column called V2 in a df called "nameSource".

I transposed "nameSource", using:

```
> wideNameSource<-as.data.frame(t(nameSource))
```

In the following step, I eliminated V1 from "wideNameSource" and created a new df called "JustNames". (V1 was a numeric column with values 1:200). This produced a df with a single column that contained the character strings I wanted to use as column names. These are sequenced in the same order I want to apply them to my "target" df.

```
> JustNames<-subset(wideNameSource[2,])
```

I then tried to bind the values in the "JustNames" df to the top of the "target" df using:

```
> targetWithColNames<-rbind(JustNames,target)
```

But I got a stream of warning messages like the following:

```
1: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = c(0.35717, 0.82226,  ... :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

and all the (numeric) data in the targetWithColNames df showed up as NA.

What is the simplest way to get my column names from "nameSource" to "target"?

Comment: `names(df1) <- df2$names` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your two dataframes `target` and `nameSource`:

```
colnames(target) <- nameSource$V1
```

Comment: Thank you. This is a tremendous help!